# how to iterate through a set of sets C++

Tags: c++, iterator, set, nested-sets

Pretty new to C++, only at it a week or so, I want to iterate through a set of nested sets and write each element in the inner set to a line in a file.
Each inner set has 3 elements and I want all three elements on the same line.
I have a set up as follows:

```
   // Define "bigSet" and initiate as empty set "Triplets"
   typedef set < set<string> > bigSet;
   bigSet Triplets;
```

I tried something of this sort to go through it but it gives me an error...

```
    // Iterate through and print output
    set <string>::iterator it;
    for(it = Triplets.begin(); it != Triplets.end(); it++){
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated guys thank you!

Comment: Each element of your `bigSet`, is a `set` so you need to iterate through each element in much the same way you iterate through your `bigSet`.

Comment: For future reference, always include the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
 // Iterate through and print output
    set < set <string> >::iterator it_ex; // iterator for the "outer" structure
    set <string>::iterator it_in; // iterator for the "inner" structure

    for(it_ex = Triplets.begin(); it_ex != Triplets.end(); it_ex++)
    {
        for(it_in = it_ex->begin(); it_in != it_ex->end(); it_in++)   
            cout << *it_in << ", ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you declare the iterators before the `for`?  It's very unidiomatic.  (Declaring iterators in a `for` is one place where `auto` is appropriate, it you have C++11.  In fact, I think it's really why `auto` was added to the language.)

Comment: Agree, it was just written this way to improve readability and for better understanding of a newbie. `auto` is great but not the thing to use unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Triplets is not a `set<string>`; it is a `set<set<string>>`; each item in Triplets is itself a `set`, than can contain several strings.

The iterator must match the type of the container; with two levels of nested containers, you should iterate twice:

```
set<set<string>>::iterator it;
set<string>::iterator it2;
for(it = Triplets.begin(); it != Triplets.end(); it++) {
    for (it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2) {
        cout << *it2 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NeilKirk indeed; edited my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

`Triplets` is type `set < set<string> >` and therefore requires an iterator of type `set < set<string> >::iterator` or `bigSet::iterator`. It isn't type `set <string>`. You could also use `const_iterator`.

Note that iterating `Triplets` gives you an iterator to another set, and not a string.

Also consider

```
for (const auto& i : Triplets)
{
    for (const auto& j : i)
    {
        cout << j << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error because `Triplets.begin()` is not of type `set<string>::iterator`, it's `set<set<string>>::iterator`.

What you need to do is have two loops: one for iterating over the outer set and one for the inner.

```
set<set<string>>::iterator it;
for(it = Triplets.begin(); it != Triplets.end(); ++it)
{
    set<string>::iterator it2;
    for(it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
    {
        cout << *it2;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

If you use increment/decrement operators (`++`/`--`) on iterators, it might be better to use the prefix versions (`++it`) instead of the suffix ones (`it++`). This is because the suffix ones create a copy of the iterator before it is incremented (and that copy is then returned) but in cases like this, you have no need for it.

Moreover, if you're using C++11, you can use the range-based for loops and `auto` keyword, which simplify things a lot:

```
for(const auto &innerSet : Triplets)
{
    for(const auto &innerSetElement : innerSet)
    {
        cout << innerSetElement;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Much better, but I wouldn't use `auto` in a range based `for`.  For anything other than a classic iterator, not spelling out the type is obfuscation.

Comment: True but that depends on the code, if you name it properly it'll be fine. Here I named the references like that so it's easier for OP to understand what's hiding there but still show `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

First: if they're triplets, are you sure that `std::set` is the type you
want for the inner values.  Perhaps a `class` would be more
appropriate, in which case, you define an `operator<<` for the `class,
and your simple loop works perfectly.  Something like:

```
class Triplet
{
    std::string x;
    std::string y;
    std::string z;
public:
    //  Constructors to enforce that none of the entries are identical...
    //  Accessors, etc.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Triplet )
    {
        dest << x << ", " << y << ", " << z;
        return dest;
    }
};
```

And then to output:

```
for ( Triplet const& elem : Triplets ) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

Otherwise: you need to define the format you want for the output.  In
particular, you'll probably want a separator between the strings in the
line, for example.  Which means you probably cannot use a range based
`for`, at least not for the inner loop.  You would need something like:

```
for ( std::set<std::string> const& triplet : Triplets ) {
    for ( auto it = triplet.cbegin(); it != triplet.cend(); ++it ) {
        if ( it != triplet.cebegin() ) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << *it;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

(If the set of triplets is large, you'll definitely want to consider
replacing `std::endl` with `'\n'`.  But of course, if it is really
large, you probably won't be outputting to `std::cout`.)